# Is homology unnecessary what computing the number of holes in a space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Why can't the number of holes simply be determined by dividing the number of distinct edges  with the number of distinct vertices?
For example a torus defined by equatig opposite sides of a sheet of paper and equating appropriate points, one gets that there are only 2 distinct sides and no 
Boundaries making its 1st homology ZxZ . So a torus has 2 normal holes meaning there are on a torus 2 distinct closed loops up to homotopy.

Comment: How many holes does a Klein bottle have?  The real projective plane?

Comment: What exactly is the "number of holes"? What if you want the group itself rather than just the Betti number? What if you're working with a space besides a closed, orientable surface?

Comment: Singular Homology is defined for *all* spaces, where the idea of a "hole" might not be geometrically clear. Your example is for a triangulated compact $2$-dimensional manifold, which is an extremely nice case of a topological space. As Perturbative points out in their answer, even the Euler characteristic (an important invariant for surfaces) is defined for a general space in terms of ranks of homology groups, regardless of if it's triangulable or not.

Comment: @Randall Are you suggesting that RP2 has a hole? Should torsion in homology be considered as classifying holes or not? This is something that has always confused me.

Comment: @anomaly I have a "simplier" question: what's a hole?

Comment: @freakish: Indeed. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer the question in your title which as I take it asks

> Is homology unnecessary in computing the number of holes in a topological space?

Well the point of homology theory is to find computable invariants for a topological space $X$, those being the $n$-th homology groups $H_n(X)$.

If you have $2$-dimensional topological manifolds (called *surfaces*), that are either orientable or non-orientable, counting their "holes", which would mean determining their *genus* does give you one *particular* invariant via the Euler-characteristic which is $2-2g$ for orientable surfaces and $2-g$ for non-orientable, connected closed surfaces.

But the Euler-Characteristic can actually be defined in terms of homology, because for any finite CW Complex $X$, the Euler characteristic $\chi(X)$ is $\chi(X) = \sum_n (-1)^n \operatorname{rank}(H_n(X))$.

The take away from this is that homology gives you invariants that are far more general and powerful than "counting the number of holes" in topological spaces.

Comment: I guess the point is which is the least sufficient amount of algebraic structure about a cyclic model of a space that completely describes it's topology, if that can even be done. Is homology enough to completely describe topology(non metrical properties)?

Comment: @Schaurberger Could you clarify what you mean by "a cyclic model of a space"?

Comment: @Schaurberger homology is a homotopy invariant. And as such obviously it cannot completely describe all topological properties. For example homology of all $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the same (trivial) and yet these spaces have different dimension (which can be defined purely in topological terms).